# Foreach element create one element after it on click (error warning)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So for a form I'd like to create an error message after each element which is invalid, onclick of the submit button.

I have almost got it right, except it adds the span twice after the element (because two elements are invalid). I need to to add it once, to both invalid elements.

So my JS/jquery (yes, I know, I mixed it :p):

```
function checkrequired() {
 var nbform = document.getElementById("userpanel");
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[required]');
 elements.forEach(element => {
  if (element.value === "") {
   nbform.classList.add('submitted-form-invalid');
   $('.show-error').after("<span class='col-sm-12' style='color:red;'> Name is required.</span>");
  } else {
   return true;
  }
});
```

How it looks:

[image]

I also know it adds it twice, instead of once, because it adds it foreach element. But I don't know how to surpass this. Anyone?

EDIT:

I came up with the next Javascript, this idea is all that I need. It doesn't need to be really complicated:

```
function checkrequired() {
 var el = document.createElement("div");
 el.setAttribute('class', 'error-message');
 el.innerHTML = "Dit veld is verplicht";
 var x = document.querySelectorAll('.show-error');
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].appendChild(el);
  }
 }
```

The only problem now is that it only appends the child to the sconds div with class "error-message". Not both.

Comment: You can try giving a different ID to each input and check their value separately

Comment: I want to use it on multiple pages, with different forms and some with 2, some with 10 input fields. That's why I'm trying to iterate it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// select your inputs with an id
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#voornaam');

    $("button").click(function(){
    elements.forEach(element => {
      if (element.value === ""&& element.nextSibling.id !="error") {
        $("<span class='col-sm-12 error' id='error' style='color:red;'> Name is required.</span>").insertAfter(element);
        return 
      }
      else return true
    })  
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.show-error')` returns an array of elements. For all these elements you are adding the span after it checks invalid. I think plain js gives you more control here.

So here's an example snippet in plain vanilla js.

Maybe [this jsFiddle](https://testbed.nicon.nl/showFiddle/mruyzafv) is helpfull too. And remember: checking in the browser will not render a server side check unnecessary.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", checkRequired);

const setError = (elem, remove) => {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.classList.add("foutmelding");
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(` vul svp ${elem.getAttribute("placeholder")} in`));
  elem.insertAdjacentElement("afterEnd", span);
};

function checkRequired(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "check") {
    document.querySelectorAll(".foutmelding")
      .forEach(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el));
    const validMsg = document.querySelector("#formValidation");
    validMsg.dataset.invalid = "";
    document.querySelectorAll('[required]')
      .forEach(element => {
        if (element.value.trim() === "") {
          setError(element);
          validMsg.dataset.invalid = "onvolledig ingevuld";
        }
      });
    validMsg.dataset.invalid = validMsg.dataset.invalid || "all checks out well";  
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  margin: 0.3rem 0;
}

.foutmelding,
.formulierMelding {
  color: red;
}

.formulierMelding:before {
  content: attr(data-invalid);
}
```

```html
<div id="theForm">
  <input type="text" id="voornaam" placeholder="voornaam" required><br>
  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="e-mailadres" required>
</div>
<button id="check">Check</button>
<span id="formValidation" data-invalid class="formulierMelding"></span>
```

Comment: Problem is I'm trying to do it without adding error messages in html in my code and only add it with JS. If I would, I can just set the error message on invisible and change it to display block, like you did. Thanks though, this is what I first came up with aswell.

Comment: Ok, let me adjust the example

Comment: Done. It's now dynamically creating span, using the `placeholder` attribute for its message

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand half of what you commented. I only just started on Javascript. Let me edit my question, because I came up with something easier. But it doesn't work fully yet. kooilnc

Comment: "I only just started on Javascript". In that case I would advise to refrain from creating complex forms and learn the basics of html, css and [ecmascript](https://javascript.info/). Create small snippets from what you learned (e.g. a form with one input field). If you understand more, try adding complexity.